# Cython: Link to library and call function

Tags: c, shared-libraries, cython

I am trying to write a Cython wrapper for a C Library. I have read through the docs carefully but I must be missing something since I cannot get the following simple Cython code to work.

I created a shared library from the following:

mathlib.c

```
#include "mathlib.h"

int add_one(int x){
  return x + 1;
}
```

mathlib.h

```
extern int add_one(int x);
```

Then I created the library like so:

> gcc -c mathlib.c
> gcc -shared -o libmathlib.so  mathlib.o -lm

My Cython files are mathlib.pyx, cmathlib.pyd, and setup.py

cymathlib.pyx

```
from mathlib cimport add_one  

def add_one_c(int x):  
   print add_one(x)  
   return x
```

mathlib.pyd

```
cdef extern from "mathlib.h":  
    int add_one(int x)
```

setup.py

```
from distutils.core import setup  
from distutils.extension import Extension  
from Cython.Build import cythonize  

setup(
    ext_modules = cythonize([Extension("cymathlib", ["cymathlib.pyx"])], libraries ["mathlib"])
)
```

The module cymathlib.so is created but when I attempt to import it in Python I get the following error: ImportError: dlopen(./cymathlib.so, 2): Symbol not found: _add_one  Referenced from: ./cymathlib.so Expected in: flat namespace  in ./cymathlib.so"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like something went wrong with your `Extension` specification, which should be something like:

```
ext_modules = cythonize([Extension("cymathlib", 
                                   ["cymathlib.pyx"], 
                                   libraries=["mathlib"],
                                   library_dirs=["/place/path/to/libmathlib.so/here"]
                                   )])
```

To be able to use the module, it must be able to find `libmathlib.so` at run time, since it will look in that file for the actual implementation of `add_one`. Apart from copying the file to /usr/lib or /usr/local/lib (and running ldconfig again), you can also set an environment variable to make sure the library can be found:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/place/full/path/to/libmathlib.so/here
```

It's also possible to add the C code into the python module you're creating (so no libmathlib.so will need to be compiled or used anymore). You just need to add the `mathlib.c` file to the list of cython sources:

```
ext_modules = cythonize([Extension("cymathlib", 
                                   ["cymathlib.pyx","mathlib.c"]
                                   )])
```

Comment: I have tried everything you suggested here. export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib and put libmathlib.so in /usr/local/lib and /usr/lib. and added library_dirs=["/usr/local/lib"] I am getting the same error

Comment: In your original `cythonize` line, the `libraries` was in the wrong place (had to be inside `Extension()`), did you fix that?

Comment: I've put some code that works for me at https://bitbucket.org/brmtron/mathlibcythontest . Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks that did it! My Extension() had the wrong syntax.

Comment: if you're getting `ImportError: libxyz.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`, [you need to set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` before starting Python interpreter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36827871/cython-unable-to-find-shared-object-file)