# Cython unable to find shared object file

Tags: python, linker, ipython, cython

I am trying to link to my own C library from Cython, following the directions I've found on the web, including this answer:

[Using Cython To Link Python To A Shared Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16993927/using-cython-to-link-python-to-a-shared-library)

I am running IPython through Spyder.

My setup.py looks like this:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize
import numpy as np

setup(
  ext_modules = cythonize(
      [Extension("*",["*.pyx"],
                 libraries =["MyLib"],
                 extra_compile_args = ["-fopenmp","-O3"],
                 extra_link_args=["-L/path/to/lib"])
                 ]),
  include_dirs = [np.get_include()],
)
```

The file `libMyLib.so` is in `/path/to/lib` and it compiles fine.

I have a Python script in my IPython profile startup folder that does this

```
try:
  os.environ["LD_LIBRARY_PATH"] += ":/path/to/lib"
except KeyError:
  os.environ["LD_LIBRARY_PATH"] = "/path/to/lib"
```

I can confirm that this is running, because if I type `os.environ["LD_LIBRARY_PATH"]` into the IPython interpreter, it returns `/path/to/lib`

But when I try to load the Cython module (i.e. `import mycythonmodule`) I get:

```
ImportError: libMyLib.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I've also tried putting libMyLib.so in other places to see if cython would find it:

- In the directory where Python is running
- On the Python path
- In the same folder as the cython module

But it still doesn't find the shared library.  The only way I can get it to find the library is by dropping it in `/usr/lib`, but I don't want it there, I want to be able to set the library path.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 6):

I'm self-answering, in case anyone else runs into the same problem.  Looks like the answers are here:

[Set LD_LIBRARY_PATH before importing in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23244418/set-ld-library-path-before-importing-in-python?lq=1)

[Changing LD_LIBRARY_PATH at runtime for ctypes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/856116/changing-ld-library-path-at-runtime-for-ctypes?lq=1)

According to these answers (and my experience), the linker reads LD_LIBRARY_PATH when python is launched, so changing it from within python doesn't have any useful effect, at least not the effect I was hoping for.  The only solution is to either wrap python in a shell script that sets LD_LIBRARY_PATH, or else drop the shared object somewhere on the linker search path.

Kind of a pain, but it is what it is.

Answer (score 3):

I have fixed it by change setup.py.

1. I have a C++ dynamic shared library called "libtmsmdreader.so". and a header file named "TmsMdReader.hpp"
2. I wrapper C++ shared library to cython library called "tmsmdreader-pythonxxxxxx.so"

> ```
> from setuptools import setup 
> from distutils.extension import Extension
> from Cython.Build import cythonize
>
> setup(
>     name="tmsmdreader",
>     ext_modules=cythonize([
>         Extension(
>             name="tmsmdreader",
>             language="c++",
>             sources=["TmsMdReaderApi.pyx"],
>             libraries=["tmsmdreader"],
>             library_dirs=["."],
>             include_dirs=["."],
>             extra_compile_args=["-std=c++14"],
>             compiler_directives={'language_level': 3},
>             runtime_library_dirs=["."])
>             ]))
> ```

**library_dirs=["."] and runtime_library_dirs=["."] can fixed LD_LIBRARY_PATH if libtmsmdreader.so in python scripy directory**