# Cythonized extension library dependency is incorrect

Tags: python, linker, cython

Checking dependencies with `ldd` on the *.so file produced by Cython, the dependencies contains `myLib.o` instead of `libforcython.o`

I do not grasp why it is trying to reach a `myLib.o` instead of `libforcython` as indicated in my `setup.py` .

During python execution of the module that produces an error similar to [Cython unable to find shared object file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36827871/356440) . However contrary to the included links and answer, my problem does not seem to happen during the python initialization, but rather during the cythonization itself.

---

using these files:

`example.pyx` :

```
cdef extern from "myLib.h":
    void testFunction ()
```

`setup.py`:

```
from distutils.core import setup 
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize


pythoncallsc_extension = Extension (
    name = "pythoncallsc",
    sources=["./example.pyx"],
    libraries=["forcython"])

setup ( name = "pythoncallsc",
        ext_modules = cythonize ([pythoncallsc_extension]))
```

---

When I look at the log generated by `python3 setup.py build_ext --inplace` I can then clearly see in the commandline launching gcc, and it contains:

```
... -lforcython -lpython3.7m ...
```

So clearly gcc is linking against my library `libforcython`.
The lib contains:

- header myLib.h
- generated libforcython.so file for the function `void testFunction(void)`.

This lib is built separately and elsewhere in my system. I have checked the include and lib and they are clearly in the $PATH of my cython project.

---

The cythonization produces the library `pythoncallsc.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so`

But against all my expectations when I do:

```
ldd pythoncallsc.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so

linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffee40fb000)
myLib.o => not found                     <=== HERE ???
libpython3.7m.so.1.0 => /path/to/lib...
libpthread.so.0 => ...
libc.so.6 => ...
...
```

Why is cython producing an output that depends on a `myLib.o` file and not on `libforcython.so` ?

This myLib.o file does not exists, and consequently that produces an error when I launch my module:

```
`ImportError: myLib.o: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`
```

Any clue ?

Comment: How is forcython built? You can always link the extension in verbose mode to see what is going on.

Comment: What do you mean by link the extension in verbose mode ? Do you mean during the call to `python3 setup.py build_ext --inplace` ?

Comment: @ead libforcython is built with gcc, with a Makefile

Comment: My guess is that your shared object isn’t a shared object but a static library called like a shared object. So you need to recheck the link command of your makefile

Comment: @ead Good catch! you are right. I have stumbled with `soname` and a wrong name for the lib... `myLib.o`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case we have this error, we should check how the c library is built.

As suggested in the comments, the `libforcython` library was not built properly.

It was wrongly built using `soname` with gcc in the Makefile.

Correct:

```
gcc myLib.o -shared -fPIC -Wl,-soname,libforcython.so -o libforcython.so -lc
```

Incorrect:

```
gcc -shared -fPIC -Wl,-soname,myLib.o -o libforcython.so myLib.o -lc
```

In this case soname is not really useful because I don't use a version number for the library: a simpler use case.